# study visa application for Canada

Tags: canada, student-visa, study

I am submitting my student visa application. I have some confusion regarding these points:

1. If my brother is permanent resident, does it affect my application in any bad way?
2. What other information regarding my brother should I provide the embassy, along with my application?

Comment: Is there a question asking about friends or family you may have in Canada?

Comment: The Form IMM 5645 asks the applicant to list immediate family (father/mother/siblings), along with their address and occupation and, if the if the applicant is married, wife & children (and whether they will accompany).

Answer (score 1):

It is routine in visa applications to be asked questions about family, and a relative in Canada may have a bearing on your application. You should provide all relevant information and how it might affect your application will depend on your individual circumstances.

Do you plan to live with your brother while attending school, is he in a position to sponsor you or to provide some financial support, do you intend to remain in Canada after your program ends to live, work, reside?  Visa applicants are expected to be open and honest; anything less can affect both your short and long term goals and aspirations.